# Git Fetch vs Pull: Different Results, Not Sure Why

Tags: git

I usually do a `git fetch origin` followed by a `git merge remotes/origin/master`, but was getting a `Already up-to-date` response.  I knew this wasn't true.  A `git pull origin` worked fine and brought in the changes.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you have used `git merge origin/master` instead?

Comment: Doing a `git remotes -a` didn't show that as an option.

Comment: origin/master would be the same as remotes/origin/master

Comment: Can you post the output of `git show-ref`. Is there a chance you've created a branch called `remotes/origin/master` by mistake?

Comment: Is your currently checked out branch tracking origin/master?  If it isn't that could explain the difference.

Comment: What branch are you on and what are its configured `remote` and `merge` settings?

Answer (score 1):

When you did:

```
$ git fetch origin
```

you were not getting the origin/master branch.  Assume you were getting origin/other.  Then when you did:

```
$ git merge remotes/origin/master
```

because there was nothing new on origin/master (you never fetched it) there was nothing to merge.  You got 'already up-to-date'.  As you know, when you did:

```
$ git pull origin
```

there was a merge to perform because 'pull' did a fetch (of origin/other) and then a merge (of origin/other).  You should be able to see which branches are configured for 'pull' and 'push' with

```
$ git remote show origin
```

Fix it with:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch --track master origin/master
```